# <span> onclick event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple modal popup when I click a sign-up button. The modal opens just fine by changing `display: none` to `display: block` but I can't get it to close from clicking the `<span>` tag.

The click event isn't firing on the `<span>` but it is firing when clicking outside of the container. I have no idea why. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the HTML:

```
<a id="modalBtn" href="#0">Get started</a>
  <div id="modalPopup" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <div>
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button id="quickstart-sign-in" href="#">Log in</button>
        <button id ="quickstart-sign-up" href="#">Sign up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the JS:

```
var modalPopup = document.getElementById('modalPopup');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
var close = document.getElementsByClassName('close');

// Opens modal on modalBtn click
modalBtn.onclick = function() {
modalPopup.style.display = "block";
}

// Closes the modal on 'X' click
close.onclick = function() {
modalPopup.style.display = "none";
console.log('wtf why is this not working')
}

// Closes the modal on outside window click
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modalPopup) {
    modalPopup.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3n1mpaex/1/

Sorry if this has been asked before, I searched around a bit and couldn't quite find the answer I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array. You are attaching 'onclick' to the array instead of the span.

So you can just simply update your function as follows.

```
close[0].onclick = function() {
 modalPopup.style.display = "none";
 console.log('wtf why is this not working')
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3n1mpaex/3/

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` return collection/array so you can use `close[0]` instead of `close` 
[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n1mpaex/2/)

```js
// Get modal elements
var modalPopup = document.getElementById('modalPopup');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
var close = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
// Opens modal on modalBtn click
modalBtn.onclick = function() {
    modalPopup.style.display = "block";
  }
  // Closes the modal on 'X' click
close[0].onclick = function() {
    modalPopup.style.display = "none";
    console.log('wtf why is this not working')
  }
  // Closes the modal on
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modalPopup) {
    modalPopup.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 150px auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 375px;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a id="modalBtn" href="#0">CLICK HERE</a>
<div id="modalPopup" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div>
      <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <button id="quickstart-sign-in" href="#">Log in</button>
      <button id="quickstart-sign-up" href="#">Sign up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `close` class into **id** (`<span id="close"></span>`). **That's it**! :) HAPPY CODING! 
Check this out:

```js
// Get modal elements
var modalPopup = document.getElementById('modalPopup');
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
var close = document.getElementById('close');
// Opens modal on modalBtn click
modalBtn.onclick = function() {
    modalPopup.style.display = "block";
  }
  // Closes the modal on 'X' click
close.onclick = function() {
    modalPopup.style.display = "none";
    console.log('It is now working')
  }
  // Closes the modal on
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modalPopup) {
    modalPopup.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 150px auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 375px;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}


/* The Close Button */

#close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#close:hover,
#close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a id="modalBtn" href="#0">CLICK HERE</a>
<div id="modalPopup" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span id="close">&times;</span>
    <div>
      <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <button id="quickstart-sign-in" href="#">Log in</button>
      <button id="quickstart-sign-up" href="#">Sign up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```